# Spamassassin DKIM DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, spamassassin, dkim, cpan

Here is the setup where I encounter my issues :

My computer has the IP 10.6.2.5.
There is a DNS server ns.isp6.lab with the IP 10.6.2.4 (I can reach it).

My computer has Postfix + Dovecot + SpamAssassin installed. I receive emails signed with DKIM from the domain isp6.lab.
They're signed with this domain key : mail._domainkey.isp6.lab

When I do `dig mail._domainkey.isp6.lab TXT` I get an answer with the public RSA key.

The problem is that Spammassassin doesn't find it, here is a part the header of a received email :

```
X-Spam-HAM-Report: 
* -1.0 ALL_TRUSTED Passed through trusted hosts only via SMTP
*  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
*      valid
*  0.0 T_DKIM_INVALID DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid
```

So I activated the debug logs in SpamAssassin and here is what I found :

```
cat spamd.log | grep dkim

Tue Oct  7 16:38:50 2014 [21673] dbg: dkim: performing public key lookup and signature verification
Tue Oct  7 16:39:00 2014 [21673] dbg: dkim: DKIM, i=@isp6.lab, d=isp6.lab, s=mail, a=rsa-sha256, c=relaxed/simple, invalid, matches author domain
Tue Oct  7 16:39:00 2014 [21673] dbg: dkim: signature verification result: INVALID (PUBLIC KEY: DNS QUERY TIMEOUT FOR MAIL._DOMAINKEY.ISP6.LAB)
```

I checked my `/etc/resolv.conf`:
domain isp6.lab
search isp6.lab
nameserver 10.6.2.4

I am now searching for hours on this issues (it doesn't seem well documented), I checked that I had all CPAN required modules, etc; I really have no idea what else I could do.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit : Maybe something can be done in the NET::DNS module? I don't really understand how all these modules are used, configured, and interact with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you hit bug related with NET::DNS and spamassassin. It explained in [this blog](https://major.io/2014/06/20/fixing-broken-dns-lookups-in-spamassassin/) and this [SA mailing list](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/spamassassin/users/185470). The excerpt from the blog

> Net::DNS version 0.76 changed the field name holding a set of nameservers in a Net::DNS::Resolver object: it used to be ‘nameservers’, but is now split into two fields: ‘nameserver4′ and ‘nameserver6′.
>
> Mail/SpamAssassin/DnsResolver.pm relied on the internal field name of a Net::DNS::Resolver object to obtain a default list of recursive name servers, so the change in Net::DNS broke that.

#### Solution:

Check your repo, if they have fixed the issue in newer release. If not, you can apply the patch manually from [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/trunk/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/DnsResolver.pm?r1=1603518&r2=1603517&pathrev=1603518)

Comment: Thanks !! After seeing your answer, I updated most of my modules with CPAN, and also realized the new versions weren't installed at the same path than the previous ones. I just deleted the previous version of DnsResolver and some others, and it worked :)