# Azure DNS does not lookup SPF policies for certain domains

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, spf

I run my own mail server on an Azure Linux VM with Postfix. Since I was under heavy spam attack I reinforced my mail server security measures.

Without going into the security things, today I noticed something particularly unusual.

Postfix was not getting mail from some well known domains. Only some

```
#  /var/log/mail
postfix/smtpd[40702]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from xxxx.ing.net[xx.xx.xx.xx]: 451 4.3.5 <prvs=2022b5a257=xxxxx@ing.com>: Sender address rejected: Server configuration problem; from=<xxxxxxx@ing.com> to=<xxxxxxxxxx> proto=ESMTP helo=<xxxx.ing.net>

# /var/log/warn
postfix/smtpd[32944]: warning: problem talking to server private/spf-policy: Connection timed out
```

What I dumbly did was to ping for SPF record on ing.com / ing.net

From my Windows box nslookup

```
 ing.com
Server:  [8.8.8.8]
Address:  8.8.8.8

Risposta da un server non autorevole:
ing.com text =

        "MS=ms77059065"
ing.com text =

        "v=spf1 include:_spf.ing.net ip4:91.209.197.6 ip4:89.20.160.55 ip4:78.136.53.254 ip4:95.138.135.251 ip4:92.52.81.2 ip4:146.148.26.249 ip4:83.231.160.132 ip4:83.231.160.128/26 ip4:212.187.169.64/26"
        " include:_spf_mx.solvinity.com include:mailplus.nl ip4:24.157.48.85 ip4:141.155.214.85 ip4:160.34.64.28 ip4:192.254.112.185 ip4:118.127.87.207 ip4:128.242.118.200 ip4:62.73.172.35 ip4:83.217.248.35 ip4:91.209.197.7 -all"
ing.com text =

        "adobe-idp-site-verification=8b81f7b92ccac0b65bab7d47f9fcecaeda6f04ac870b79133d8ac54be7b53534"
ing.com text =
```

From the email server box nslookup

```
> nslookup
> set type=txt
> ing.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
```

From mail server box setting the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 returns the same SPF payload.

Question is: what is causing this issue with TXT DNS resolution in Azure VM? Before blindly changing the system DNS settings, I would like to understand the error and its cause, and why happening only on Azure default DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that switching the DNS to Google public DNS works and is currently the only way to get SPF working.

It happens that if a DNS query is larger than 512 bytes it can't be transmitted over the standard UDP. `nslookup`, from what I could see, switches to TCP automagically.

But the DNS server has to support TCP querying, i.e. must be listening on TCP 53.

The problem **seems** to be with Azure infrastructure. Their DNS (`168.63.129.16`) is likely misconfigured, simply because it timeouts when using TCP.

```
$ telnet 168.63.129.16 53
Trying 168.63.129.16...
Connected to 168.63.129.16.
Escape character is '^]'.
eee





^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
```

(Sleep)

Such problem does not occur with other DNS services, so this allows me to think it's not a problem with the appliance's local firewall `SuSEfirewall`.

Switching `/etc/resolv.conf` to any other public DNS (e.g. `8.8.8.8`) allows TCP querying and SPF returns to work.

One drawback is that a few spam blacklist are not very friendly with Google DNS.

For example I had to comment in my `main.cf`

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
#        reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com,
```

Logs have been rotated, so I can't recall the exact error message I got with that RBL.